# iTunes Sync Calendars does not show Outlook

Tags: iphone, itunes, ms-office, calendar

I want to sync my iPhone calendars with Outlook via iTunes.
[Here are the instructions from Microsoft support Office](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/synchronize-outlook-and-apple-iphone-or-ipod-touch-calendars-be7a12eb-fe76-4346-ae13-b54249db7f9c), which require iTunes.
Step four says:

> 4. Under Calendars, click Sync calendars from, and then click Outlook.

But there is no such option in my iTunes which I just downloaded.
Check the image, that does only show **Sync Calendars**, but not chance to choose ***from*** neither ***Outlook***:

[image]
However, [this page](https://www.tenorshare.com/iphone-tips/sync-outlook-calendar-with-iphone.html#1) and [this one](https://www.akruto.com/how-to-set-up-outlook-on-iphone-and-boost-productivity/) show a similar image with that possibility:

[image]

Can anyone help on this, please?

Comment: The second screen is not my computer... it does not appear on my iTunes

Comment: It looks like you're currently syncing your calendar to iCloud.  When you do that then the section in iTunes will be disabled.

Comment: @fsb, how do I proceed to reach the section in iTunes where *Sync Calendars from*  + *Outlook* appears? I just follow the instructions on the first link, but do not see how to reach that.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to my own question in an [issue opened in Apple Communites.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250322564?answerId=250609946022#250609946022)

Basically it says that, when using iCloud to sync your contents across all your devices (which is my case), it is not possible to use iTunes to sync the Calendars and Contacts.

From https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201253 :

> If you use iCloud or other services like Apple Music to keep your content up to date across all of your devices, syncing through iTunes might be turned off.

So instead of using iTunes, I just use iCloud for Windows which synced Calendars, Contacts & Mail.
Below is an image of my work Calendar created in Outlook plus the imported ones from iCloud:

[image]